# What are the metaphysics inherent to magic in the Game of Thrones series?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This upcoming semester I am teaching the class "Philosophy of Game of Thrones" and I have been through a month long process of trying to establish a universal metaphysic inherent to the story. I have found that if one subtracts the magic from this story all we are left with is the Hobbesian state of nature (life is nasty, brutish and short) [as confirmed in Foreign Affairs magazine](http://www.foreignaffairs.com/articles/137360/charli-carpenter/game-of-thrones-as-theory?page=show).

However, the "magic" in the show adds another facet to the story's metaphysics predominately by way of the Lord of Light. This begs the question (as well as my begging for help ;) what are the rules, conditions, and context for magic to become manifest/actualized?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is this class based on the show or based in the books? In either case it may be too soon to provide a complete answer as neither is complete and the further you go the more prevalent magic becomes. Also at least in the books it seems magic by way of the old gods (warging, the Wall, the vow of the Black Watch) is at least as prevalent as R'hllor's even if not as flashy. Then there is the god of the Faceless Men.

Comment: Well, one of their final exam questions requires them to give the most PROBABLE answer to the question I asked above. So while we don't know the story's resolution yet, there must be a non-spiritual explanation (non-spiritual due to GRRM's hatred of LOST's resolution) that reveals the true nature of magic.

Comment: But @Mr.Mindor, the only god of the Faceless Men is Death. :P (Yes, I am aware the god is called the Many Faced God, but still it's supposed to be the multiple personifications of Death, at least that's what I got out of it.)

Comment: @ardentsonata  It may well be there is no entity behind the name and the god exists only on a conceptual level, but there is some _magic_ there in the ability of the Faceless Men to change their appearance.

Comment: As there isn't really anything in-cannon to suggest how magic works, I'm not sure how one could claim any answer to this question is more _probable_ than another. I think the best you can hope for is _plausible_. Any answer that supports the different types of magic present in the story should be equally acceptable.

Comment: What qualifies something as non-spiritual?

Comment: I can't believe some can truly be serious in making exams of game of thrones philosophy lessons and seeing himself qualified to evaluate the tests. Can't tell if this is more arrogant or stupid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can invoke mind-matter duality. Certain mental structures affect matter structures. The classic "what is the mechanism of interaction if they are two separate things" doesn't really work, because ultimately, there isn't any "mechanism" of interaction between anything. I.e. if you say particles interact a certain way because of so and so "mechanism", well what is the mechanism that causes that mechanism to work? What is the mechanism that causes the more elementary particles to interact a certain way? And so forth and so forth -- an infinite regress. The "mechanism" for how 'mind' interacts with 'matter' is that is just does, just as particles interact a certain way 'just because'.

Also, not all metaphysics regards it in terms of black-and-white duality, but rather different forms of subtle energy or numerous planes of existence.

Sound has long been believed in esotericism to have spiritual effects, i.e. mantras.

Different frequencies also can have some pretty neat physical effects that make it appear as though matter spontaneously responds to sound in unique ways (look up youtube videos of cymatics, including the sounding of Aum in the Great Pyramid by steven halpern)

Suppose a certain mental thoughtform manifests when combined with the right sound patterns.

There is also the simple fact that things at the quantum level, according to physics, are random and chaotic. We are told that a particle is basically an emergence from a more fundamental field, IIRC. What is the force that causes a sustained pattern/manifestation of even a single atom? Some esoteric schools of thought call this "fohat". You can call it anything, but it could be used to say that something about a practitioner of magic allows this universal manifestation/sustaining force to flow through/mesh with the practicioner's mind & sound.

Comment: OK- I like the answer but I think I may not have been specific enough. I'm not seeking a Cartesian theory of doubt path; rather, it seems as though Will (in the Schopenhauer sense, i.e. the universe has an underlying Will that is actualized by conscious beings) allows for magic to become actualized. Have you noticed anything in that regard?

Comment: @Mariovingian Well, the force that causes an atom to be actualized and sustained from the chaotic quantum state could be thought of as the result of a "unit" of will and/or a universal will acting on the most basic level. Magic becoming actualized is a system of conscious intent acting upon this universal will.

Comment: @Mariovingian Due to the diversity of magic ranging from foresight to alchemy, you really have to have some sort of consciousness or will structure that is intermeshed with the material structure so that it can be manipulated through various means. 

A simple system of conscious intent manifesting through the universal will might not be enough, given the complex rituals needed to manipulate things in a magical way. You need some sort of structure that is being manipulated other than just the matter.

Comment: I'm savvy with your train of thought! Are you suggesting that a type epistemic scaffolding (lack of a better term) is what's allowing the magic to occur?

Comment: @Mariovingian If by scaffolding you mean one is built on the other, not exactly. They would have to be intermeshed, i.e. the influence would have to be two-directional, since manipulating the physical structure is part of manipulating the non-physical, which in turn manipulates the physical. Likewise, it takes a physical practitioner of magic to manipulate the non-physical/magical/will/consciousness structures, which in turn manipulates the physical. 

More like a tai-chi, or even a multi-network of different aspects.

Comment: @Mariovingian since you're not supposed to have discussion in comments, I've made a chat room if you want. I'll be around for a bit.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10016/got?tab=general

Comment: I dig it! I had an inkling that the answer would reside in Eastern thought. I can make that work. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this answer have to do with Game of Thrones?

Comment: @TLP GoT is just context is the question was asked in. The question itself is not really specific to GoT. I don't think there is anything in-cannon that can be used to explain how magic might work. It seems to be a generic provide plausible metaphysics to explain the existence of magic.

Comment: -1 This isn't a real answer. You don't even mention Game of Thrones, when it's in the title of the actual question. This website isn't the place to discuss metaphysics (or for open ended debate, no matter how interesting). Please narrow down the focus.

Comment: @Andres F The author stated that he was trying to establish a universal metaphysic for magic. Do you read? The books do not give any, and thus the answer is open to any system that is plausible and comprehensive.

Comment: No, the author asked entirely in the context of Game of Thrones. But suppose he hadn't; suppose he had asked about magic in general. In that case, his entire question (and your answer) would fall outside the scope of this website. Scifi.SE isn't meant for open & long-winded debate, but for specific questions with concrete, focused answers. That's not to say your answer isn't interesting; it's just _off topic_ (and IMO, "not a real answer").

Comment: To elaborate, your answer reads like what you would discuss with your friends in a pub, while philosophizing about the role of magic in fiction. Interesting? Maybe. But off-topic and it doesn't answer the question about how magic works in GoT. (In fact, you don't quote the books or reference author GRRM in any way).

Comment: @AndresF. You mean besides the source I cited? Any good narrative has an inherent metaphysic to it, or else it's bad writing. Therefore, if GRRM is writing about magic then there must be a metaphysical explanation for its existence; afterall, you can't "magic" magic into existence. So how do you discover the cause and effect of magic inherent to the story, YOU HAVE TO DO A METAPHYSICAL ANALYSIS! Sorry, but that's Literature, Philosophy & Religion 101. Futhermore, you can't answer a question by using Red Herrings like "it's pub talk." Reread the original question and you will have your context

Comment: @Mariovingian "According to..." doesn't mention anything GoT or GRRM said. Sorry, but scifi.se isn't the place to discuss _metaphysics_ in vague, general terms. It is a place to discuss particular details of specific works of SF/fantasy fiction. In particular, broad literary debate is outside the scope of this website. Compare this answer (which confusingly, you accepted) with [Thaddeus' excellent answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39107/770): on-topic, with examples and taxonomy from the actual fictional work.

Comment: @AndresF. I'm not going to dragged into a fallacious debate, so i'm sorry for asking a question that requires a deeper and less superficial answer; however, I think Varys and Littlefinger would admire my inquiries.

Comment: @Mariovingian You edited your comment above. The source _YOU_ cited is relevant and explicitly mentions GoT. But this answer makes no mention of your source (or GRRM or GoT); hence it's _off-topic_. I'm talking about James' answer, not your original question.

Comment: *I.e. if you say particles interact a certain way because of so and so "mechanism", well what is the mechanism that causes that mechanism to work?* The claim that laws of nature need a "mechanism" is not one taken seriously by modern scientists, it shows up as #17 on the classic [crackpot index](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html). The problem people have with interactive mind/body dualism is that no one can propose any coherent *laws* governing the interaction.

Comment: (continued) If you had mathematically-defined states of "mind" and there were mathematical rules governing their effect on states of "matter", and this was testable, that would solve the issue--scientists wouldn't then ask for a "mechanism" to explain the laws themselves, physics is just about finding the correct laws rather than asking where the laws come from. But no one has ever come up with a testable proposal for such laws, and few scientists see any reason to think human behavior can't just be explained in terms of physical events in the brain.

Answer (score 24):

**Magic in the Game of Thrones universe was once diverse and quite powerful. Though it is currently far less powerful, with the return of the Dragons, magic is slowly making its way  back into the world. The effects of magic in the modern world are little more than legend but in its heyday, Magic was responsible for feats of amazing creation such as [The Wall](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wall) of Westeros made of ice and magic over 8,000 years ago.**

From the Game of Thrones Wiki regarding [Magic](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Magic):

> - Magic, occasionally referred to as "the higher mysteries" is a powerful but little understood force in the world. In Westeros it is believed, particularly by the Maesters of the Citadel, that magic, if it ever existed, is now gone from the world.
> - Only one in every hundred Maesters, Luwin among them, bother to study the subject long enough to earn a Valyrian steel link for their chains. Nevertheless, in Essos, magic is still practiced, particularly in the eastern corners of the continent, although its effects and the power of its practitioners are frequently questioned.

The best known practitioners of magic included: [The Faceless Men](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Faceless_Men), [Warlocks](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warlocks), [Maegi](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Maegi), [Pyromancers](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemists%27_Guild) and the [Red Priests](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Priest).

### Types of magic

- [Blood magic](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_magic): practiced by maegi, involving sacrifice of both animals and humans. It is forbidden among the Dothraki.
- [Warging](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warg): the ability to enter the mind of an animal and experience and/or control its actions.
- [Greensight](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Greensight): experiencing prophetic dreams. Associated with the Greenseers of the Children of the Forest.
- [Shadow-birthing](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow): Red priestesses may give birth to shadows shortly after being impregnated by a man.
- Bilocation: the ability to be physically present and perform actions in several places at once. See: [Pyat Pree, Warlock](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/GameOfThronesEssos)
- Kiss of Life: Red Priests have the ability to resurrect the newly dead.
- Dragon Magic: Daenerys Targaryen resistance to fire is unexplained.

### As to metaphysics

Metaphysics is a traditional branch of philosophy concerned with explaining the fundamental nature of being and the world, although the term is not easily defined. Traditionally, metaphysics attempts to answer two basic questions in the broadest possible terms:

- What is ultimately there?
- What is it like?

As far as seeking an underlying metaphysical nature to magic, none is ever explained, there is no sign of the Universe seeking to know itself through magic use, or of a supreme power whose origins and powers are clearly defined or understood.

- Many magicks seem able to be manifest from a variety of sources but no underlying structure, deity or source of magic is evident except for the correlation between Dragons and the waxing and waning of magic.
- When Dragons are ascendent so is the power of magic. When dragons waned and died, magic became a mysterious mummery, repeated but often without an expectation of result. During those times, magic users were considered little more than charlatans.

In it way, magic functioned like a technology without a power source. When Dragons were not in existence, practitioners of magic might be able to manifest low-powered magics such as divination, but only the most powerful of magic users could manifest magical abilities during the times without Dragons.

- The question could be asked: What relationship does the ascendency of Dragonkind and the prevalence of magic bear on the existence of magic itself? Are Dragons the source of the magic or merely an indicator that magical power is returning to the world?
- GRRM does not seem to be painting a relationship of deity to magic, since without Dragons, most deities were quiescent and worshipped because they once appeared to have power.

Magic unfortunately appears to be little more than another means to an end, a technology to be exploited by those who have the power to manipulate it, weaponize it and employ it effectively.

- It is not seen being utilized to understand the fundamental aspects of the universe or even being used to study itself for a better understanding of the source of magic.
- Granted we are never given enough time to see magic and its relationship to the world to know for certain if schools of thought were developed around the metaphysical aspects of the origins of magic or whether there was a single or supreme source of magical power in their universe.

Comment: +1 But, also think the Dany Unburnt aspect and Faceless Men face changes should be mentioned. Bilocation? I don't remeber that one.

Comment: How does this answer provide a universal metaphysic, as the OP asked for?

Comment: I understand that there are different types of magic and magic has been said to be responsible for certain feats (like the Wall), but hasn't GRRM made it evident that what is perceived as magic can actually be explained via empiricle means. For example, Giants-- thought to be magical-- are simply an indigenous species that live in the north. And if the Wall really was made of magic then why does it erode with the seasons, or are you saying the effects of magic are transitory?

Comment: @Thaddeus I appreciate the taxonomy of magic, but that wasn't what I was asking for.

Comment: @Mariovigian a purely non-magical wall of these dimensions is not possible. [Can the Ice Wall in Game of Thrones Survive Science?](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2013/03/game-of-thrones-ice-wall-science/)

Comment: @Mr.Mindor That's what the builder of the 10ft wall said to the man with an 11ft ladder ;-)

Comment: And if all we were contending with were an 10 foot wall, that would not be a problem. This is a problem of epic physical contradiction. Without magic, gravity would destroy a wall made purely of ice in short order or render the building of such a structure as useless in the extreme. And yes, I believe all magic is transitory in the GoT universe. Subject to entropy and disorder over time. Magic is just another technology to be utilized as needed. It just happens to be a fairly durable one, if it's done right.

Comment: @Mariovigian Ice on a glacial scale flows. This flow happens at a molecular level. A structure 700ft tall, 40+ feet wide(at the top) and 300miles long would certainly act like a glacier. It would not only flow downward (in place) getting wider and wider at the base, but it would drift horizontally as well off of the hills Bran built it into to 'strengthen the structure' to fill low points and valleys. After just 1000 years it wouldn't be in the same place, and it wouldn't be a wall anymore. (intially posted this in the wrong place)

Answer (score 0):

The correlation between dragons and magic does NOT imply causality-

'Magic' has anecdotally grown in efficacy circa their apparent arrival...
But to conclude that dragons generate it rather than simply herald or portend the waxing of 'magical energy' would be erroneous and a reductive fallacy.

Please recall that the white walkers were the first 'magical' or mythical creatures to reappear in this saga-
Followed by ominous portents and a reawakening of 'magical powers' in the stark family blood(of the first men) line
Then finally the red comet and dragons-

The dragons are merely the most notable landmark on the recent timeline of events that the fallible third person POV would associate to current changes in the metaphysical dynamics of their lives....
As stated by melisandre and the pyromancers, etc.

The name of the saga is " a song of fire and ice " draw your own conclusions about the metaphysical nature of magic in this mythos as it may relate to duality and polar changes of state within the same continuum...
 But since the word 'physic' is the root of metaphysic perhaps doing a simple wiki read on physical nature of fire and it's typical chemical constituency might help??? (As would actually reading the books-)
One eyebrow quietly raised? I'll give you a hint . 
Fire and water are made of, and require the exact same stuff, as well as products of each other.
fuel and oxidizer. Diametric DUALITY of nature? 
Seems rather like particle physics and physical chemistry in our "non-magical world", doesn't it? Think charged and relaxed atomic states, binary data, two magnetic poles making one continuum field---

You may also recall that it has been said more than once that it isn't known whether 'the white walkers bring the winter or it brings them, but the two are connected'
Coincidentally white walkers being made of ice (a crystal with inherent harmonic resonance) can be shattered by obsidian in much the same way as glass can by ceramic.
Physics.

Realizing that the seasons are incalculable and erratic, you might deduce this planet to be in a binary star system...
Physics and cosmology-

If this isn't coming together for you I'll just spell it out-
The "metaphysics" and physics of 'magic' in the world of fire and ice is a literary metaphorical trope for the paradoxical nature of dualities and continuums in our own world, and the way in which many seemingly unrelated or distantly related systems of organization are actually codependent or interdependent in a synergistic way influencing state changes in one another-

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit random and I'm just throwing this in to be taken wherever by whomever. 
I was just thinking about Arya's training with regards to becoming "invisible" and how that could be related to the notion in quantum physics of the observer and the observed. In order to have the power, one must become no one. In other words. The less one is observed (by others or themselves) the less tethered they are to physical reality. If you have no name then you are not defined. If one is absent from the observations of others, then the only thing able to collapse the wave is ones own observation of ones self.